# Keystroke to surround selected with tags in Eclipse (or cancel auto-closing)

Tags: xml, eclipse, tags, keyboard-shortcuts, auto-close

I am used to an editor that does not auto-close tags, but I'm exploring Eclipse.

Sometimes, I already have a block of text entered, and would like to put matching tags around it.

If I type at the beginning of the block, I end up with the closing tag (yay!) before the beginning of the block (boo.)  I can think of two solutions but don't see them in the keybindings preflet:

1. Some way to select text, hit a key combo, enter the tag name, and have it surround the selected text with matching tags.
2. Some way to, at the moment the auto-close tag comes up, hit a key combo ( you know, shorter than "ctrl+shift+rightarrow four times then delete") to get rid of the auto-close tag.  Then I can just go to where I want it and type "

How can I do this, or do what I'm looking for a different way, with a quick-to-use keybinding?

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
Window > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor > Typing > uncheck "Insert a matching end tag" at When typing a start tag
```

Comment: Thanks, but I normally do like this feature.  I don't want to have to set a preference every time I happen to already have content that I want to wrap.  I'd like something that can be a single keycombo to cancel.  (Because probably I want it more often enabled than disabled.)